# Upload file on Ambari Apache from local system using python

Tags: python, hadoop, upload, ambari

I want to upload my a csv file daily on Ambari Apache. I've tried manuplating multiple solutions avaliable online to upload files of Google and other equivalent platforms. I have also tried methods like sftp to help me achieve it, but still have not found a solution. Please recommend any tips, ideas or methods on how should I achieve it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://attic.apache.org/projects/ambari.html Ambari was retired in January, are you sure it's what you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Ambari method to do this.  You can create a [custom service](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Defining+a+Custom+Service) in ambari that would run.  This would enable you to have ambari self contain the code and execute it.  Out of the box Ambari wouldn't technically be running the script, you'd have to run it on a Master/Slave but you might be able to work around that by running an agent on ambari and making it a slave.  If it's acceptable you could just have this service installed on one slave and have it push/pull the appropriate file to Ambari.

There are others that have implemented this on just one machine and you can google for how they make sure it's run on just one machine.

Comment: Will try creating this setup, Thank You !